# Client proxy is not creating methods

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I have an error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'`. I followed every step to create webservice properly (Wrote service first, compiled it and viewed it in the browser. Then created a service reference using "add service reference" wizard). Here is the WP code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         ServiceReference1.Service1Client proxy = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        string myName = "Nick";
        AgeTxtBlck.Text = proxy.GetAgeAsync(myName);
    }
```

And the service implementation is:

```
public string GetAge(string myName)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext data = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var myAge = from a in data.Users where a.uName == myName select a;
        return GetAge(myName).ToString();
    }
```

To make my problem more clear here is the client generated proxy:

```
 public partial class Service1Client : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<PhoneApp1.ServiceReference1.IService1>, PhoneApp1.ServiceReference1.IService1 {

    private BeginOperationDelegate onBeginGetAgeDelegate;
    private EndOperationDelegate onEndGetAgeDelegate;
    private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback onGetAgeCompletedDelegate;
    private BeginOperationDelegate onBeginOpenDelegate;
    private EndOperationDelegate onEndOpenDelegate;
    private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback onOpenCompletedDelegate;
    private BeginOperationDelegate onBeginCloseDelegate;
    private EndOperationDelegate onEndCloseDelegate;

    private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback onCloseCompletedDelegate;

    public Service1Client() {
    }

    public Service1Client(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }

    public Service1Client(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public Service1Client(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public Service1Client(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }
```

Also I don't know if its relevant to the question but in the Reference.cs file I found this:

```
 public void GetAgeAsync(string myName) {
        this.GetAgeAsync(myName, null);
    }
```

Is it supposed to be void? Is there any solution to this problem?
**EDIT**: To PoweredByOrange. My Web.config is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Database1ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>

          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My contract is:

```
    namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
         string GetAge(string myName);
    }
}
```

And I'm not sure what do you mean by "service implementation object" (sorry, I'm a beginner), but I found this in the Reference.cs (correct me if I posted the wrong code)

```
public partial class GetAgeCompletedEventArgs : System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs {
    private object[] results;
    public GetAgeCompletedEventArgs(object[] results, System.Exception exception, bool cancelled, object userState) : 
            base(exception, cancelled, userState) {
        this.results = results;
    }
```

EDIT: Additional Reference.cs code:

```
public void GetAgeAsync(string myName, object userState) {
        if ((this.onBeginGetAgeDelegate == null)) {
            this.onBeginGetAgeDelegate = new BeginOperationDelegate(this.OnBeginGetAge);
        }
        if ((this.onEndGetAgeDelegate == null)) {
            this.onEndGetAgeDelegate = new EndOperationDelegate(this.OnEndGetAge);
        }
        if ((this.onGetAgeCompletedDelegate == null)) {
            this.onGetAgeCompletedDelegate = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnGetAgeCompleted);
        }
        base.InvokeAsync(this.onBeginGetAgeDelegate, new object[] {
                    myName}, this.onEndGetAgeDelegate, this.onGetAgeCompletedDelegate, userState);
    }
```

Comment: The reference gets generated from a contract, which is an interface you defined somewhere. More specifically, `PhoneApp1.ServiceReference1.IService1` has a void method called `GetAge`. You need to change the signature on the interface and regenerate the proxy.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange, I have only `string GetAge(string myName);` under the `[OperationContract]` in the IService1.cs file. I started this project from scratch and added only this method. Is it a right signature that I have now?

Comment: Strange. How are you generating the proxy?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange, I'm using Visual Studio's Add Service Reference Dialog.

Comment: Yes but what do you type in in the URL?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange, `http://localhost:62835/Service1.svc`

Comment: Post your Web.config, contract and the service implementation object.

Comment: There should be a non-async version of the method available that has a return type of string. Does your service class implement `IService1`?

Comment: Please post the code of the `this.GetAgeAsync(myName, null)` method in the proxy. I'm curious to know what that second parameter is.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, added to the question the code what I found below the `this.GetAgeAsync(myName, null)`.

Comment: Wait! Why are you using the `Async` version? You're using it in a synchronous manner. In the `Async` methods, the result is returned in the `EventArgs`, not in the method return value.

Comment: @Cory, I think it implements, I have this `public class Service1 : IService1` in my Service1.svc. About the non-async version of the method available that has a return type of string - I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I can't turn off `allow generation of asynchronous operations`, its grayed out. I'm not familiar with `EventArgs`. Could you please answer how my code will look like considering `Async` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the event-based async form of the operation, you need something like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client proxy = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    proxy.GetAgeAsyncCompleted += SetAgeText;
    string myName = "Nick";
    proxy.GetAgeAsync(myName);
}

private void SetAgeText(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetAgeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    AgeTxtBlck.Text = (string) e.Result[0];
}
```

Comment: I've got an error: `The type or namespace name 'GetAgeCompletedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I bet you could figure that out for yourself, but I bet it's really `ServiceReference1.GetAgeCompletedEventArgs`.

Comment: It helped, but one more error appeared: `Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'`. I fixed it like `AgeTxtBlck.Text = e.Result;`.

Comment: Ahah! I think you left out a little code above. Probably the property `Result` is defined as `get{return (string) this.result[0];}` so that my cast and `[0]` are not required.